# How to filter NON colored cell in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column in which some of the cells have a color background and some do not, is it possible to filter on the `non` colored cells.

I have tried the code below but does not work nor can I find anything by searching the web.

I have also tried setting `RGB(255, 255, 255)` in hopes of filtering on `white` background

```
 With ws
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("A1", Cells(lRow, lCol)).Cells.AutoFilter
    .Range("A1", Cells(lRow, lCol)).Cells.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="<>RGB(255, 199, 206)", Operator:=xlFilterCellColor

    On Error Resume Next
    .UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0

    .AutoFilterMode = False 
End With
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the Operator for `selecting` default background color `Operator:=xlFilterNoFill`

you can remove or not the Criteria1:=RGB(Red, Blue, Green)

```
With ws
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("A1", Cells(lRow, lCol)).Cells.AutoFilter
    .Range("A1", Cells(lRow, lCol)).Cells.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 199, 206), Operator:=xlFilterNoFill 'to filter on default background color

    On Error Resume Next
    .UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0

   .AutoFilterMode = False 
End With
```

Answer (score 3):

To find records that have no fill color, use the operator **xlFilterNoFill** and do not specify
any criteria.

```
.Range("A2").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:=xlFilterNoFill
```

Example:

```
  Sub FilterNoFontColor()

     Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=6, Operator:=xlFilterNoFill

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own function if you can add a column and then use it to filter...

In this case I have wrote a function accepting two parameters one which identifies the cell containing the source color I want to filter on, the second containing the cell I want to evaluate.  It returns a 1 if they match 0 if not, and then all I do is filter on that.

```
Function MatchesColor(SourceColor As Range, EvalColor As Range)

  If SourceColor.Interior.ColorIndex = EvalColor.Interior.ColorIndex Then
    MatchesColor = 1
  Else
    MatchesColor = 0
  End If

End Function
```

[image]