# Autofilter different cell color with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a question.
If I want to sort cell with different color than RGB(255, 199, 206), it meaning I've Filter it all, how I can perform that in VBA.

```
Sub Macro1()
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$5202").AutoFilter field:=8, Criteria1:="<>RGB(255, 199, 206)", Operator:=xlFilterCellColor

End sub
```

I try this way cause, when you have a lot of row in one sheet, and each row have a different data. It take a massive time to Filter or Custom Sort, so VBA make it short

Comment: You can perform the same filters in VBA as in Excel. I am afraid that there is no filter option to see all rows that are *not* formatted with a specific color

Comment: I try this way cause, when you have a lot of row in one sheet, and each row have a different data
It take a massive time to Fillter or Custom Sort, so VBA make it short

Comment: Please clarify, are you trying to filter on cell color because you think it will be faster, or for some other reason. What would you filter on, if you would not filter on cell color?

Comment: Yes, I try filter on cell color and duplicate cell because I think it faster, than now I realize, it's not faster than I thought

Comment: So your question is what sometimes is referred to as "an XY question". You want to solve problem X and think that Y will solve it, so you ask how to do Y. Then people spend time on the wrong solution to the actual problem. Take the lesson with you and avoid it in the future, thank you. Perhaps you could emphasize it in an edit of your question and perhaps in the answer too, as both question and answer are somewhat pointless.

Comment: Oh wait is there anyway else I can filter or sort data, not using Autofilter? If there is, I will use it and close this question

Comment: No, I mean of course that you filter / sort on cell colors instead of cell content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some tests and it looks that filtering by color takes longer than filtering by strings, even using an array of (string) colors.

The following code assumes that the headers are **in the first row** and the filtering will be done from the second one to the last. The code takes about 10 seconds to filter 5202 rows. It does not contain formulas. With formulas, even with formulas for format conditioning it should take longer. In such a case it should be good to use `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` at the beginning and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` at the end, but I would like to know how much it takes without any optimization.

The workaround involves the next mechanism: All interior color values are placed in an array and dropped at once in the first empty column. In the same time, a dictionary is used to keep the unique color values, except the one to be excluded. Then, the filtering is done on that last column, using an array extracted from the dictionary keys:

```
Sub testFilterByColor()
   'the code needs a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime'
   Dim arrColors(), sh As Worksheet, rngCol As Range, lastEmptyCol As Long, lastR As Long, arrCo
   Dim dict As New scripting.Dictionary, i As Long, retCol As Long, colIntCol As String, rngIntC As Range
   Dim exclColor As Long
   
   exclColor = RGB(255, 199, 206) 'the color to be excluded from the filter
   colIntCol = "intCol"          'The header of the new column keepinig the interior color (conditional formatted included)
   Set sh = ActiveSheet        'use here the sheet you need
   sh.AutoFilterMode = False 'remove filter, if exists
   
   'find the cell where the interior color to be placed and then used for filtering using an array
   Set rngIntC = sh.rows(1).Find(what:=colIntCol, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
   If rngIntC Is Nothing Then   'if the header has not been found:
        lastEmptyCol = sh.cells(1, sh.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1 'last empty column (in row 1)
        sh.cells(1, lastEmptyCol).Value = "intCol"                                          'place the reference header
   Else                                 'if the header has been found
        lastEmptyCol = rngIntC.Column 'calculate the last column in a different way
        If sh.cells(rows.count, lastEmptyCol).End(xlUp).row > 1 Then 'if rows are more than 1, clear contents of the range:
             sh.Range(rngIntC.Offset(1), sh.cells(sh.cells(rows.count, lastEmptyCol).End(xlUp).row, lastEmptyCol)).ClearContents
        End If
   End If
   lastR = sh.Range("H" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row
   Set rngCol = Range("H2:H5202")                            'the range with the colored cells
   ReDim arrCol(1 To rngCol.count, 1 To 1)                  'redim the array to keep the interior color (array to make the code faster)
   For i = 2 To lastR
        retCol = intColor(sh.Range("H" & i))                   'the Long color using a function
        arrCol(i - 1, 1) = retCol                                    'place the value in the array
        If retCol <> exclColor Then                              'if the color is not the one to be excluded
            If Not dict.Exists(CStr(retCol)) Then               'collect the unique colors, without the one to be excluded
                dict.Add CStr(retCol), 1                            'make a dictionary key if not already exist
            End If
        End If
   Next
   sh.cells(2, lastEmptyCol).Resize(UBound(arrCol), 1) = arrCol 'drop the array content at once, in the last empty column
   arrColors = dict.Keys                                          'extract the colors (as strings) in an array to be used as Criteria1
   'filter the range according to the newly created column:
   sh.Range(sh.Range("A2"), sh.cells(lastR, lastEmptyCol)).AutoFilter field:=lastEmptyCol, Criteria1:=arrColors, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

Please, test it and send some feedback.

The code can work without the required reference, using late binding, but it is good to have it, in order to receive intellisense suggestions. If adding it looks difficult, please use the next code which will add it automatically. Please, run it firstly, save the workbook and then run the first code:

```
Sub addScrRunTimeRef()
  'Add a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime':
  'In case of error ('Programmatic access to Visual Basic Project not trusted'):
  'Options->Trust Center->Trust Center Settings->Macro Settings->Developer Macro Settings->
  '         check "Trust access to the VBA project object model"
  On Error Resume Next
  Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll"
  If err.Number = 32813 Then
        err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
        MsgBox "The reference already exists...": Exit Sub
  Else
        On Error GoTo 0
        MsgBox """Microsoft Scripting Runtime"" reference added successfully..."
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer through this link, turn out I can use another Operator:=xlFilterNoFill
[How to filter NON colored cell in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24089983/12238225)

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$5202").AutoFilter field:=8, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 199, 206), Operator:=xlFilterNoFill
```

But it still take a lot of time to perform the task, so is there another way to make Filter perform better ?

Comment: Do you mean that the above code works? I mean for `Criteria1:=<>RGB(255, 199, 206)`? Filtering by colors works for only one color. In the above code, `Criteria1` **should be eliminated** (or use it in a different way:  `Criteria1:="<>" & RGB(255, 199, 206)`, since it does not matter). If you need to filter only by cells not having any interior color, it works. But your question stated "different color than RGB(255, 199, 206)", letting us believe that **there are more other colors**... I have in mind a workaround for more such colors, but if duration is the problem, it will not help...

Comment: Oh sorry, I just edit it, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 199, 206), Operator:=xlFilterNoFill

Comment: That part does not matter at all for filtering in this way. It matters only for VBA syntax. You can delete `Criteria1`. But my point was not this one... I tried referring to those "many other colors" to be filtered...

Comment: Yes it have so many color in Data, cause I use conditional formating

Comment: If you are telling about that only now, it is worst... The interior for conditional Formatted cells cannot be returned by using `Cell.Interior.Color`. Anyhow, you have a solution **which works only for not colored cells and DUE TO THE FACT THAT ANY CONDITIONAL FORMATTING IS APLIED**. I cannot help to improve the filtering duration. Using such a way to deal with your data (which looks to be a big range) is a bad habit, on my taste. You cannot improve anything, I am afraid.